# display image from URL in image view

Tags: android

I have been trying many of the codes that have been posted on stackoverflow itself. However, none have worked for me so far. I'm new to android and there's probably something I'm overlooking. Kindly help fix this code -

```
package com.alphageeks.pespitstop;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.entity.BufferedHttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Vop extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vop);

    Button bnot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnot);
    Button bcant = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcant);
    Button bcal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bcal);
    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    final Toast disp = null;

    bnot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-bEff6i-vWoUHpWS3h1VUR4ZkE/edit?usp=sharing");
                //try this url = "http://0.tqn.com/d/webclipart/1/0/5/l/4/floral-icon-5.jpg"
                HttpGet httpRequest = null;

                httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                        .execute(httpRequest);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
                InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

                img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    disp.makeText(Vop.this, "error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });




}
```

}

Comment: Your code generate some error or the image just don't appear?

Comment: Have you given Internet Permission in Manifest ? If you have error logs can you please post in the question ?

Comment: You can always use a library. Picasso is useful for this stuff. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @FedericoPerez sorry but I don't think is a good solution to add a library to such simple problem, but that's my opinion and I'm just shering it

Comment: @GhostDerfel There are no errors in the code. The image just doesn't appear.

Comment: @Kedarnath Yes, i have included the internet permissions in the manifest. Is there any other permission that i have to include?

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

**1)** The URL your want is actually:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pgF2BkPGEdp5KuKD535q0DNL-SkXqiaPGmeQt-F0wA-GZ3GLIu2WaOGI72i0TzlxI-Uub4FoFtY

**2)** You'll need to download the image in a background `Thread`, like an `AsyncTask`, otherwise you'll throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

```
private class ImageWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(YOUR_URL);
            input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (final IOException ignored) {
                    // Nothing to do
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            // Set the image here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (this is in case if you don't get any exceptions, otherwise you probably do networking on UI thread and that results in error, then you may ignore my reply):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient
                        .execute(httpRequest);


ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();

                byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();       

Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);

            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look in this tutorial.
I hope it can solve your problem.

https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/diplayinganimage

Or this website that have more detailed tutorial on how to display image from URL.
Don't forget to include permission in the manifest.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/

Answer (score 0):

use picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/ is easy with less code example `Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-bEff6i-vWoUHpWS3h1VUR4ZkE/edit?usp=sharing");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..it may be help you..

```
URL url = new URL("YourUrl");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```